# PGSQL query to get all records of a column containing line breaks

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the shortest Pgsql query to get all records that contain a line-break in a given column ?

Comment: Add to your question the initial data and the expected result, as well as what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
select * from table_name where column_name ~ '\n';
```